I tryna run this Python file to let a minesweeper game solves itself but it didn't
I was assigned a group project in Intro to AI course at uni.
The topic was: "implement an AI to play a puzzle game by itself using a blind search algo and a heuristic search algo."
The required programming language is Python. If me and my friends use other languages, our project grade will reduce by half.
We pick Minesweeper as the game, DFS for blind search.
This is our code for DFS:
from memory_profiler import profile
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showerror
import time



class solution:
    
    def __init__(self, matrix, last_flag = None):
        self.size = len(matrix)   
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.last_flag = last_flag
        self.list_flag = []
        list_cl = []
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                if matrix[i][j] == -1 or matrix[i][j] == -2:
                    list_cl += [(i,j)]
        self.list_close = list_cl

   
    def print_matrix(self):
        for row in self.matrix:
            for element in row:
                print(element, end=' ')
            print()
    
    
    def place_flag(self):
        rf,cf = (0,0)
        if self.last_flag == None:
            rf,cf = self.list_close[0]
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.list_close)-1):
                if self.last_flag == self.list_close[i]:
                    rf,cf = self.list_close[i+1]
                    break
        self.matrix[rf][cf] = -2
        self.list_flag += [(rf,cf)]
        self.last_flag = (rf,cf)
        
    
    def replace_flag(self):

        if self.last_flag == self.list_close[-1]:
            r,c = self.last_flag
            self.matrix[r][c] = -1
            self.list_flag = self.list_flag[:-1]
            self.last_flag = self.list_flag[-1]
            self.replace_flag()
        else:
            r,c = self.last_flag
            self.matrix[r][c] = -1
            self.list_flag = self.list_flag[:-1]
            for i in range(len(self.list_close)-1):
                if self.last_flag == self.list_close[i]:
                    rf,cf = self.list_close[i+1]
            self.matrix[rf][cf] = -2
            self.last_flag = (rf,cf)
            self.list_flag += [(rf,cf)]
 
    def next_stage(self):
        if self.last_flag == None:
            is_flag_valid = True
        else:
            is_flag_valid = self.check_valid_flag(self.last_flag)

        if is_flag_valid == True:
            self.place_flag()
        else:
            self.replace_flag()


    def get_arround_cell(self, cell):
        r,c = cell
        list_temp = [(r-1,c),(r+1,c),(r,c-1),(r,c+1),(r-1,c+1),(r-1,c-1),(r+1,c+1),(r+1,c-1),]
        list = [i for i in list_temp if i[1]>=0 and i[0]>=0 and i[1]<=self.size-1 and i[0]<=self.size-1]
        return list
   
    def count_flag(self,cell):
        list_arround = self.get_arround_cell(cell)
        num_flag = 0
        for i in list_arround:
            if self.matrix[i[0]][i[1]] == -2:
                num_flag += 1
        return num_flag
    

    def compare_value_with_num_flag(self, cell):
        value = self.matrix[cell[0]][cell[1]]
        num_flag = self.count_flag(cell)
        if num_flag < value :
            return -1
        if num_flag == value:
            return 0
        if num_flag > value:
            return 1
            
   
    def check_valid_flag(self, flag):
        if flag == self.list_close[-1]:
            return False
        list_cell_arround_flag = self.get_arround_cell(flag) 
        for cell in list_cell_arround_flag:
            if self.matrix[cell[0]][cell[1]] >=0:
                if self.compare_value_with_num_flag(cell) > 0:
                    return False    
        return True
    
  
    def check_end(self):
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                if self.matrix[i][j] >=0:
                    val = self.compare_value_with_num_flag((i,j))
                    if val == -1 or val == 1:
                        return False
        return True
    
    
    def create_matrix(self):
        rows = len(self.matrix)
        cols = len(self.matrix[0])

        new_matrix = []

        for i in range(0,self.size):
            new_matrix += [[]]
            for j in range(0,self.size):
                if self.matrix[i][j] == -1 :
                    new_matrix[i] += " "
                elif self.matrix[i][j] == -2:
                    new_matrix[i] += ''
                else:
                    new_matrix[i] += str(self.matrix[i][j])

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                label = tk.Label(window, text=str(new_matrix[i][j]), borderwidth=1, relief="solid", width=8, height=3)
                label.grid(row=i, column=j)
        update_button = tk.Button(window, text="Next Step", command=self.update_matrix)
        update_button.grid(row=self.size + 1, columnspan=self.size)
        end_button = tk.Button(window, text="End", command=self.end)
        end_button.grid(row=self.size + 2, columnspan=self.size)

    def end(self):
        isFinish = False
        while isFinish == False:
            self.next_stage()
            isFinish = self.check_end()
        self.end_matrix()

    def update_matrix(self):
             
            
            self.next_stage()
            finish = self.check_end()
            if finish == True:
                self.end_matrix()
                return
            for widget in window.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_forget()

            self.create_matrix()

    def end_matrix(self):

            rows = len(self.matrix)
            cols = len(self.matrix[0])

            new_matrix = []

            for i in range(0,self.size):
                new_matrix += [[]]
                for j in range(0,self.size):
                    if self.matrix[i][j] == -1 or self.matrix[i][j] == -3:
                        new_matrix[i] += " "
                    elif self.matrix[i][j] == -2:
                        new_matrix[i] += ''
                    else:
                        new_matrix[i] += str(self.matrix[i][j])
            for widget in window.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_forget()

            for i in range(rows):
                for j in range(cols):
                    label = tk.Label(window, text=str(new_matrix[i][j]), borderwidth=1, relief="solid", width=8, height=3)
                    label.grid(row=i, column=j)

    def emp_cell_0(self, cell):
        list_arround = self.get_arround_cell(cell)
        list_arround = [i for i in list_arround if self.matrix[i[0]][i[1]] == -1]
        for i in list_arround:
            self.matrix[i[0]][i[1]] = -3
        
    

                


    def DFS(self):
     
        global window
        window = tk.Tk()
        self.create_matrix()    
        window.mainloop()


        

grid1 = [
    [-1, 1, 2, -1, -1, 2, -1],
    [2, -1, -1, 3, 3, 3, -1],
    [2, -1, 3, 2, -1, -1, 1],
    [1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, 0],
    [1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2],
    [-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 3, -1],
]


sl = solution(grid1, None)
sl.DFS()



            



I run:
python3 <this-file-name.py on my Ubuntu-running laptop.
There will be a popup window displaying a 7x7 matrix of a predetermined minesweeper game. (written in grid1 variable). Also, there will be "Next Step" and "End" button placed at the bottom center.
Initially, "Next Step" is intended to display the next step to solve the puzzle, "End" is for immediately clear the puzzle. The hyphen character '-' will be filled into the blank tiles, it represents the removed tiles. (no mine exists there)
But, "Next Step" as well as "End" did not work as expected.
As shown in the below screenshots
The pop window as soon as I run the command
Expectation
Reality (kinda like that)

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

all your images are almost the same - I don't see what is wrong.

if you want to change text on tk.Label then you have to keeps references to labels and use label["text"] = "new text". Label will not change text when you change value in matrix.

Welcome to [so]. We don't provide generalized debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. How to debug small programs, Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers

In my opinion Minesweeper is not an ideal choice for this exercise. The thing is that either a move is bad (because it triggers a bomb), or it is not. When it is bad, you cannot undo it (that would be cheating), but backtracking is a feature you need in these (blind) search approaches. So you're left with implementing game logic into your solution, so that you only play safe moves, but for those there are no bad moves. As long as a move is safe, it is a good move.
